# Get item under settings

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud, sxa-jss

I have a headless SXA site and I was wondering if it’s possible to query an item under Settings via GraphQL. I think I should start with the query example here for getting the [root item of a site](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/query-examples.html) but I’m not sure how to traverse the descendants from here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the children of the context item, you can use the below query:

```
query ListOfChildren( $contextItem: String!)

{
  contextItem: item(path: $contextItem) {
    id
    name     
    children{
            id
            displayName
          }
    }
}
```

To get the children of a specific item and filter children based on template, you can start with below query:

```
query RetrieveContentItems($itemPath: String = "/sitecore/content/Home") {
  rootItem: item(path: $itemPath)
  {
    children(includeTemplateIDs: "{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}")
    {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more details about GraphQL sample queries in these below blogs:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/useful-example-graphql-query-sitecore-context-arvind-gehlot
http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.com/2021/01/sitecore-graphql-queries.html#top

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question when we start working on XM Cloud because we are used to work with the `GetChildren()` method, but now we have to use GraphQL queries to achieve that. In the blog I refer below you will find how to use GraphQL queries to get the children of a particular item in the content tree. Basically you have to use the follow query:

```
query{
  item( 
    path: "{XXXXXXXX-E896-433B-A8E7-7A2D8CAA0D4E}" 
    language: "EN"){    
    name        
    children{
      total
      pageInfo{      
        hasNext
        endCursor        
      }
      results{
         Headline: field(name: "headline") {
              jsonValue
            }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query shows the field "headline" of the children's item on the specified item path.

https://sitecoretek.wordpress.com/2023/10/30/xm-cloud-development-tips-for-overcoming-common-challenges-part-2/